# Installation of pipenv on Windows fails

Tags: python, pipenv

I am working on a website with Django Heroku template. I want to work on this website on my Windows computer, and one of the requirements to work with Heroku and Python is to have pipenv (the project has a Pipfile).

To install pipenv on Windows, I have tried two commands in the cmd terminal, which gave approximately the same error:

```
pip install pipenv
```

results in

```
Collecting pipenv
  Using cached pipenv-11.9.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    error in pipenv setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Expected version spec in pathlib;python_version<"3.4" at ;python_version<"3.4"

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\myUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-267yrlop\pipenv\
```

And:

```
easy_install -U pipenv
```

results in

```
Searching for pipenv
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pipenv/
Best match: pipenv 11.9.0
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/aa/43/e7426676c659fa3c1db28653ceee3571efbaaec2d2795bca00212989268a/pipenv-11.9.0.tar.gz#md5=0cdefd8434dc2b30415708d517730dcb
Processing pipenv-11.9.0.tar.gz
Writing C:\Users\myUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-p2bvwljy\pipenv-11.9.0\setup.cfg
Running pipenv-11.9.0\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir C:\Users\myUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-p2bvwljy\pipenv-11.9.0\egg-dist-tmp-vfore9pv
error: Setup script exited with error in pipenv setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Expected version spec in pathlib;python_version<"3.4" at ;python_version<"3.4"
```

I don't really understand the error message. It seems like an error in the setup script of pipenv but most likely isn't. Or is it expecting a Python version lower than 3.4? (if so, how do I install it with my Python 3.5?)

EDIT: I've tried with admin rights, in and out of a virtualenv, but same result.

Comment: can you check your pip version with `pip -V`? I'm pretty sure this has to do with an outdated pip or setuptools version not being able to read the new format of setup.py

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this has to do with an outdated version of either setuptools or pip. First try updating setuptools with

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

and then installing pipenv with

```
pip install pipenv
```

If that still fails, try updating your version of pip with

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

or (because you mentioned you were on Windows)

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: I had the idea of updating pip but the issue was with setuptools. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one
#**pip install --user pipenv**

Comment: Can you expand on this? Please see [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -1):

got it from [here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)

> On Windows you can find the user base binary directory by running py
>   -m site --user-site and replacing site-packages with Scripts. For example, this could return
>   C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Python36\site-packages so you would
>   need to set your PATH to include
>   C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Python36\Scripts. You can set your
>   user PATH permanently in the Control Panel. You may need to log out
>   for the PATH changes to take effect.

i am not able to produce this is on machine, but if possible then go with [anaconda](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/windows.html) it have many libraries pre-installed

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: You are missing the original preface (from the site) in your quote which makes it out of context